Mapping multiple function parameters to static template parameters
I would like to map non-constexpr function parameters that can assume a finite set of values to static template parameters in order to be able to utilize some constexpr optimizations in the template. Consider this example:
void WrapperFunc(int A, int B)
{
  enum { ValA1 = 1, ValA2 = 4, ValB1 = 2, ValB2 = 3 };
  if (A == ValA1)
  {
    if (B == ValB1)
      Func<ValA1, ValB1>();
    else if (B == ValB2)
      Func<ValA1, ValB2>();
  }
  else if (A == ValA2)
  {
    if (B == ValB1)
      Func<ValA2, ValB1>();
    else if (B == ValB2)
      Func<ValA2, ValB2>();
  }
}

template <int A, int B>
void Func()
{
  // Do something
}

You can see that there is a lot of code-duplication there, as the test for B occurs twice in WrapperFunc. One way to resolve this is to simply split the WrapperFunc into two functions like so:
void WrapperFuncA(int A, int B)
{
  enum { ValA1 = 1, ValA2 = 4, ValB1 = 2, ValB2 = 3 };
  if (A == ValA1)
  {
    WrapperFuncB<ValA1>(B);
  }
  else if (A == ValA2)
  {
    WrapperFuncB<ValA2>(B);
  }
}

template <int A>
inline void WrapperFuncB(int B)
{
  if (B == ValB1)
    Func<A, ValB1>();
  else if (B == ValB2)
    Func<A, ValB2>();
}

However, I was wondering whether there was a nicer way of doing this with modern C++, e.g., through template aliases?

Confusing pattern ... WrapperFunc(7, 42); should do nothing whatsoever? Why is it good?

@ÖöTiib I edited my post to clarify that the function is supposed to handle a finite set of values only.

@STiFU yeah it did handle a finite set also before, but why does it take int then? Why not declare the enum outside and use that for the parameters?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I just did not want to overcomplicate the example, but maybe an enum would have been more clear.

Related to is-there-a-clean-way-to-convert-runtime-values-to-compile-time-values.

@STIFU Sometimes a mundane solution is better than an exotic one. Can you rely on a simple lookup table instead (that maps your integer combinations to the "Func" specializations you're interested, in such as std::map<std::pair<Val, Val>, void(*)()> (where "Val" is your enum of A and B), though a "std::array" has less overhead than "std::map" and may be preferable for your needs). It may be simpler than relying on arcane template techniques (if it's something you want to consider).

You might map runtime value to compile time value with std::variant:
enum EValA
{
    ValA1 = 1,
    ValA2 = 4
};

std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<EValA, EValA::ValA1>,
    std::integral_constant<EValA, EValA::ValA2>
> as_integral_constant(EValA a)
{
    switch (a) {
        case EValA::ValA1: return std::integral_constant<EValA, EValA::ValA1>{};
        case EValA::ValA2: return std::integral_constant<EValA, EValA::ValA2>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid value");
}
enum EValB
{
    ValB1 = 2,
    ValB2 = 3
};

std::variant<
    std::integral_constant<EValB, EValB::ValB1>,
    std::integral_constant<EValB, EValB::ValB2>
> as_integral_constant(EValB b)
{
    switch (b) {
        case EValB::ValB1: return std::integral_constant<EValB, EValB::ValB1>{};
        case EValB::ValB2: return std::integral_constant<EValB, EValB::ValB2>{};
    }
    throw std::runtime_error("Invalid value");
}

then, a simple usage of std::visit does the job:
void WrapperFunc(EValA a, EValB b)
{
    std::visit([](auto A, auto B){ Func<A(), B()>(); },
               as_integral_constant(a),
               as_integral_constant(b));
}


Is that a typo "EValA" instead of "EValB" in the second as_integral_constant? Other than that, this actually looks quite decent. I would probably implement those two as_integral_constant functions as lambdas so that all mapping occurs in one function, but other than that, this looks promising, thanks.

Bad copy paste indeed, typo fixed.

It mainly depends if you have to do the "conversion" at several different place or not. but conceptually, it make sense as regular function, it is not just an helper function.


I was wondering whether there was a nicer way of doing this

There's a more general way of doing this, but it doesn't necessarily qualify as nicer. The trick is to use fold expressions across ternary operators to switch on arguments without writing switch.
template<typename T, typename U>
struct concat : std::type_identity<std::tuple<T, U>>
{
};

template<typename... Ts, typename U>
struct concat<std::tuple<Ts...>, U> : std::type_identity<std::tuple<Ts..., U>>
{
};

template<typename T, typename U>
using concat_t = concat<T, U>::type;

template<typename T>
struct is_tuple : std::false_type
{
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type
{
};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_tuple_v = is_tuple<T>::value;

template<typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) tuplefy(T& x)
{
    if constexpr(is_tuple_v<T>)
        return x;
    else
        return std::tuple{x};
}

template<typename Tx, size_t nx, typename Ty, size_t ny>
constexpr auto product(const std::array<Tx, nx>& arrx, const std::array<Ty, ny>& arry, const auto&... arrs)
{
    std::array<concat_t<Tx, Ty>, nx * ny> arr{};
    auto it = arr.begin();
    for(auto& x : arrx)
        for(auto& y : arry)
            *it++ = tuple_cat(tuplefy(x), tuplefy(y));
    
    if constexpr(sizeof...(arrs) > 0)
        return product(arr, arrs...);
    else
        return arr;
}

template<int... is>
void f()
{
}

void g(int x, int y, int z)
{
    static constexpr std::array xs = {1, 2};
    static constexpr std::array ys = {10, 20, 30};
    static constexpr std::array zs = {100, 200, 300, 400};
    static constexpr auto values = product(xs, ys, zs);
    
    auto called = []<size_t... Is>(auto xyz, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        using std::get;
        bool called = ((xyz == values[Is] ?
            (f<get<0>(values[Is]), get<1>(values[Is]), get<2>(values[Is])>(), true) :
            false
        ) || ...);
        return called;
    }(std::tuple{x, y, z}, std::make_index_sequence<values.size()>{});

    if(!called)
        throw "a tantrum";
}

As demonstrated, increasing the arity and valid values both require very small code changes.
Live.

Wow, cudos to you for writing this up so quickly. However, as far as readability is concerned, I would probably not adopt this solution. Still, very interresting.
